# How to get value of Element value in org.w3c.dom.Document ?

Tags: android

I wrote some android application that get xml from some service ( using http ). 
I define object type org.w3c.dom.Document that hold this xml. 
The xml that i get from the server contain Elements and value of those Elements.

I can't get the value of those Elements. 
How can i do it ?

Comment: Search how to parse XML in android, you will find SAX , DOM , XPP parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) for `org.w3c.dom.Document`.

You will probably be doing something like getting a [`NodeList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) with [`getElementsByTagName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) then running through it and doing whatever with each [`Node`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).