# get data from web page android and tostring

Tags: android, html

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb5wO.png)

I want to get some data and save in string in my app

My aim web page is http://self.shahroodut.ac.ir/Ghaza.aspx?date=970229

I read some topics but did't help me

for example i want save

> جوجه كباب

and

> شويد پلو + تن ماهي - ش

in *string1*

and next line in *string2* . . .

I had tried some topics but not helped

I think this data's in

> table>tr>td>ol>li

but i dont know how to get them in android studio

---

**Edited** : I want to get data from that table (link that i write in top) and save theme in strings in my app programmaticly and use theme later

Comment: Its really not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @YamenNassif check it again

Comment: can you provide your code ?
Basically you need to read the data from the table using php/java/.net or whatever server language you are using and then provide an API to your application to read it

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517380/how-to-get-value-of-element-value-in-org-w3c-dom-document?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @YamenNassif thats not my website...this is the problem...i just have that link and i want to get that data from page...please open that link then u can see جوجه کباب and others data...i want to write an app that get جوجه کباب and toast it...the main problem is how to get?

Comment: @E.Abdel i realized that must use documantion.. but dont know how to use for this link pls help by write android code example ☻

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its not your website you need to read the HTML from the page, many Java libraries offers this. My recommendation would be [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).
In order to add to your android application you will need to add this to your gradle

`compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'`

also found a nice start point : [Learn to parse HTML Pages on Android with JSoup](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-parse-html-pages-on-android-with-jsoup-2a9b0da0096f)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download this page as html using any file downloader and then parse the HTML to get the data out of the table